# Flatten top-level sublists in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, mit-scheme

I am working my first project in scheme and have come across an issue. In part of my requirements, I am required to append all top-level sublists 
(e.g. `'((1 2)(3 4 (5 6))) ->  (1 2 3 4 (5 6)) and '((1 2 3)(4 5)) -> (1 2 3 4 5)`
I've managed to get it working down to a single list, but this flattens all levels:

```
 (cond
     ((null? lst)
         lst)        
     ((list? lst)
         (append2(append-subs(car lst))(append-subs(cdr lst))))
     (else
         (cons lst '())))
```

Variations of this (eg. `(else lst)` run the error `"object 6, passed as first arg to cdr, is not correct type"`. Another method I attempted is as follows:

```
    (cond
        ((null? lst)
            lst)        
        ((>= (len (cdr lst)) 0)
            (append2(append-subs(car (list lst)))(append-subs(cdr (list lst)))))
        (else
            lst)
```

Which infinitely loops. I'm at a bit of a stand still, so any help would be greatly appreciated. (Note: Use of functions other than those used here is forbidden. Limited to list, list?, if, cond, null? ...)

Comment: This is meaningless: (car (list lst)) == lst , also (cdr (list lst)) == '()

Answer (score 1):

Your list `'(e1 e2 e3)` would be like this:

```
(cons e1 (cons e2 (cons e3 '())))
```

or if you like dotted notation:

```
'(e1 . (e2 . (e3 . ())))
```

Where `en` is eiter `#f` or `#t` for `(list? en)` Your assignment is to cons `en` onto the recursion with the same level while with a list you need to append the two.

Here is a general idea how to implement it with level as an input parameter:

```
;;; flatten a list a certain levels
;;; level of zero is identity
(define (flatten-level level lst)
  (cond ((or (zero? level)
             (null? lst))
         lst)
        ;; pair? is faster but will fall through for dotted
        ((list? (car lst)) 
         (append (flatten-level <??> <??>)
                 (flatten-level <??> <??>)))
        (else 
         (cons <??>
               (flatten-level <??> <??>)))))

(flatten-level 0  '((1 2)(3 (((4 . 3))) (5 (6))) . 7))
; ==> ((1 2) (3 (((4 . 3))) (5 (6))) . 7) (aka identity)
(flatten-level 1  '((1 2)(3 (((4 . 3))) (5 (6))) . 7))
; ==> (1 2 3 (((4 . 3))) (5 (6)) . 7)
(flatten-level 99 '((1 2)(3 (((4 . 3))) (5 (6))) . 7))
; ==> (1 2 3 (4 . 3) 5 6 . 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about appending all elements of the top list:

```
(define (flatten-top-level lst)
  (apply append lst))
```

Which is practically the definition of **[append*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._append%2A%29%29)**

If  `'(a (b) (c f))` is a valid input, (first element not a list) then you can try:

```
(define (flatten-top-level lst)
  (apply append
         (map (lambda (e) (if (list? e)
                              e 
                              (list e))) ;make a list from the non-list element
         lst)))
```

2nd option: **Fold it!**

```
(define (flatten-top-level lst)
  (foldr append '() lst))
```

For a list (a b c d) where a, b, c, d are sub-lists; it is equal to:

```
(append a (append b (append c (append d '()))))
```

*Extra*: this is tail recurssive and therefore runs in linear time :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, though I have explored the usage of map and apply, I am not allowed to use either in my solution. All input elements are to be contained in lists, though, so your first suggestion is more applicable.

Comment: Are you allowed to use foldr?

Comment: Does not seem so, no.. I can create my own helper functions but use of other Scheme functions is not permitted, haha. I've written and re-written this code so many times, my brain.

Comment: I just caught your update and foldr is not allowed either. Such a headache ! Thank you so much though.